# How do you compile just a .h file in a makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a makefile that creates object files for two classes (and main) and one of those classes is just defined in a .h file. In my makefile I have a line that says

```
FileName.o: FileName.h
  g++ -c FileName.h
```

but when I try to compile it says it can't find  FileName.o

Do I have to create FileName.cpp in order to get this to compile?

Comment: In general, thinking you want to compile just a header file instead of `#include`ing it into some actual source file means you need to refactor your code.  Or maybe rethink it entirely.

Comment: compiling is what generates the object files ... did you mean when you try to link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using your class from FileName.h somewhere, aren't you? So at least one of your .cpp files should contain `#include "FileName.h"`, and .h's code will be compiled with this .cpp and you needn't compile .h's code separately.

Answer (score 6):

You don't normally attempt to compile a header (.h) file by itself. Including it into an otherwise empty .cpp file will let you compile it and produce a .o file, but it probably won't do much (if any) real good unless you've put things in the header that don't really belong in a header.

Comment: The class is really small and is manipulated by a friend class. Is there any way at all to just create and object file from that .h file even though it's not standard protocol?

Comment: @JDN You should just include the .h where it's needed. No need to compile it separately.