# C/C++ Can you compile only a header file in a makefile?

Tags: c++, c, header

Title. 
Basically in a makefile can you only compile a header file if your header file contains code to run your other c/c++ code? 
For example, if I have 
header.h, first.c, second.c and in my header file I have:

```
class header{
    first();
    second();
}
```

Will this work? thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: What do you think a header file is?

Comment: Why would you want it this way? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112851/how-do-you-compile-just-a-h-file-in-a-makefile